# Can not get any time/freq domain plots to show after execution

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, rtl-sdr

Very new to GNUradio. I started with tutorials - and in the very first tutorial, when the program runs the new tab opens but nothing is plotted. Screenshots below :

Flowgraph:
[image: Flowgraph]

Execution tab:
[image: Execution tab]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Context -
I'm using GNU radio on M2 macbook' Sonoma OS
There were no issues during installation of radioconda/GNUradio. When I first ran the program there was an error - 'xterm missing' which I did not see again.

I've gone through all the blocks and settings. Tried removing throttle and connecting the sinks directly to the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reproducing your flow graph on GNU Radio Companion 3.10.2 leads to the same results (no data).

By setting the *'maximum number of output items*' in your option block to its default value (**0**), it works, I can see the sine waves and the frequency. (https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Options)

See https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Handling_Flowgraphs for more information. The 'items' refer to the number of data chunks to be sent between the blocks, and it's normally in the order of thousands. You should only set it to something else than the default value if you have latency issues.

It's a big confusing, because in many blocks, the '*number of inputs*' parameter refers to the number of signal channels (for a sink for example), and not the size of the data chunks.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped, I'll check out the resources you mentioned to understand it better. You're right, lots of new things to keep in mind.